# Sites do not work on iPhone

Tags: apache-http-server, iphone, nginx

I'm here to consult you because I have a major problem. As the title indicates, iPhones cannot connect to the sites that are on my server. When I say iPhone, I'm not talking about Safari. I'm talking about iPhones. I did the tests with several owners of this brand, from 4s to X. Whether with Safari, Chrome or Firefox it's impossible to connect.

The strange thing is that on a given site, they can't connect to it but after I changed the DNS servers to go through Cloudflare, no more problems.

Regarding configuration, I am under Debian Stretch with Nginx 1.10.3 in reverse proxy with Apache 2.4.25 and php-fpm7.2.17.

Nginx is in charge of distributing the static elements and Apache the php. When I use an Android phone or a PC, whether with Firefox or Chrome I have no problem.

For your information, even with an HTML/CSS/JS site it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea what could cause this problem? If you need more details on server configuration, please do not hesitate.

Thank you!